# "unknown directive" when installing Phusion Passenger on Debian 8 with nginx

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

I try to install Phusion Passenger on a Debian 8 (amd64) which already has an installed nginx (the Debian default nginx package). I use the official install how-to:
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu

After `apt-get install nginx-extras passenger` I add

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
```

to the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file and try to `service nginx restart`. The restart fails with these errors:

```
Mai 29 13:20:52 nassau nginx[12880]: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "pass...32
Mai 29 13:20:52 nassau nginx[12880]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/n...ed
Mai 29 13:20:52 nassau systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, c...=1
Mai 29 13:20:52 nassau systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web s...r.
Mai 29 13:20:52 nassau systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
```

misc:

```
root@nassau:~# apt-cache policy nginx-extras
nginx-extras:
  Installed: 1.6.2-5
  Candidate: 1.6.2-5
  Version table:
     1:1.6.3-8.5.0.8~jessie1 0
        500 https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.6.2-5 0
        700 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
root@nassau:~#
```

What am I missing? How can I make it work?

Comment: Check what nginx package you have installed

Comment: I have the following deb packages installed: nginx, nginx-common and nginx-extras

Comment: Show `apt-cache policy nginx-extras`

Comment: I added the output to the question.

Comment: You have wrong version installed. Update nginx-extras

Comment: I did an `apt-get update` and an `apt-get upgrade` but it didn't upgrade any package. I'm using `deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger jessie main`. Any ideas?

Comment: `apt-get install nginx-extras=1:1.6.3-8.5.0.8~jessie1` should work